# How van I get 2 matches in a regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have xml files formatted like this:

```
<User>
<FirstName>Foo Bar</FirstName>
<CompanyName>Foo</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>bar@foo.com</EmailAddress>
</User>
<User>
...
```

I want to read through all xml files, creating as output `<CompanyName>,<EmailAddress>`, so:

```
Foo,bar@foo.com
User2,user@email.com
Blah,blah@blah.com
```

I am using the following snippet:

```
$directory = "\\PC001\Blah"


Function GetFiles ($path) {
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path) {
        if ( Test-Path $item.FullName -PathType Container) {
            GetFiles ($item.FullName)
        } else {
            $item
        }
    }
}


Foreach ($file in GetFiles($directory)) {
    If ($file.extension -eq '.test') {
        $content = Get-Content $file.fullname
        $pattern = '(?si)<CompanyName>(.*?)</CompanyName>\n<EmailAddress>(.*?)</EmailAddress>'
        $matches = [regex]::matches($content, $pattern)

        foreach ($match in $matches) {
            $matches[0].Value -replace "<.*?>" 
        }    
    }
}
```

However, `$matches` is empty so there's something wrong with my regex. If I leave out `\n<EmailAddress>(.*?)</EmailAddress>`, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Will `<CompanyName>` and `<EmailAddress>` _always_ be next to each other? And any reason you're not using the [XML parsing capabilities of Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/26/use-powershell-to-parse-an-xml-file-and-sort-the-data.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '(?si)<CompanyName>(.*?)</CompanyName>\s*<EmailAddress>(.*?)</EmailAddress>'
```

Try this.`\s` will make sure all spaces and newlines are covered.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance of `\r` character would present in that file. So change your regex like below,

```
$pattern = '(?si)<CompanyName>(.*?)</CompanyName>[\n\r]+<EmailAddress>(.*?)</EmailAddress>'
```

OR

```
$pattern = '(?si)<CompanyName>(.*?)</CompanyName>.*?<EmailAddress>(.*?)</EmailAddress>'
```